# Excel Formula to change price by 10% in the entire workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have this Excel price list in which I have separate sheets attached, and each sheet has prices mentioned in different columns. Is there any way to increase the price, for example: where there's a $ (DOLLAR) symbol mentioned in a workbook, increase those columns by 10%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any built-in function to do this, but this one
might just work. You might have to adjust your NumberFormatLocal, I assume it's "$#,##0.00" (US).
 You need to press ALT+F11 and paste the following code in "This workbook". Then call main()

```
Public Sub main()

Call CheckDollar("A")
Call CheckDollar("B")
Call CheckDollar("C")
Call CheckDollar("D")
Call CheckDollar("E")
Call CheckDollar("F")
Call CheckDollar("G")
'etc
End Sub


Public Sub CheckDollar(column As String)

Dim N As Long, i As Long


N = Cells(Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To N
' MsgBox (Cells(i, column).NumberFormatLocal)
If InStr(Cells(i, column).NumberFormatLocal, "$$") > 0 Or Cells(i, column).NumberFormatLocal = "$#,##0.00" Then
Cells(i, column).Value = (Cells(i, column).Value) * 1.1
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If you like this answer you can click on the green V to mark it as accepted answer. I also improved the code.

Comment: When I run this code all I see is a POP says General and its keep popping up? And it is not changing the price either.

Comment: Yeah that line is just there to verify the format. You can comment it out by putting a quote one the left hand side, so:    ' MsgBox (Cells(i, column).NumberFormatLocal). You will need to find out what the format is of the dollar prices.

Comment: Ok, so I went thru the entire WORKBOOK and Sheets. There are prices with $ symbol only in F and G Columns , Also I ran your code and it didnt work for me

Comment: Take a look at the main method: add all of the letters in there, so  Call CheckDollar("D")  Call CheckDollar("E")  etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164896/discussion-between-sohaib-khan-and-ole-eh-dufour).

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out on this.

Comment: No worries! Have a nice evening.